# Vue encountering problem when importing highcharts-more

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I'm trying to create a BoxPlot in Highcharts. It seems to require a module called highcharts-more. I have trouble importing.

I imported it like this:

```
import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

more(Chart);
```

However in browser console the following error appeared:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined
    at eval (highcharts-more.js?33c6:8)
    at eval (BoxPlot.vue?7d00:19)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/BoxPlot.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:933)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:770)
    at fn (app.js:130)
    at eval (BoxPlot.vue?8bce:1)
    at Module../src/components/BoxPlot.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:2420)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:770)
    at fn (app.js:130)
    at eval (BoxPlot.vue?67a8:1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I'm using highcharts version 7.1.3 and highcharts-vue 1.3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `highcharts-more` module with Highcharts:

```
import { Chart } from 'highcharts-vue';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import more from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

more(Highcharts);
```

---

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#importing-highcharts-modules

Comment: I can't find an example usage of highcharts-more on the page you referenced. But thanks, strangely, without me registering imports from 'highcharts' in anywhere, it works.

Comment: Hi @huggie, You can import and initialize `highcharts-more` in the same way as other modules.